# QTimer doesn't fire on second call

Tags: qt

I've implemented the state pattern in qt.  
Inside my EnterIdleState function, I'm hooking up a singleshot timer to start things off.  On the first call this works fine, on the second attempt however the timer doesn't fire, although the connection is made as before:

Codeflow is like this:

```
SetNewState(newIdleState());
IdleState::doWork();
SetNewState(new WorkState());
WorkdState::doWork();
SetNewState(newIdleState());
```

The SetNewState looks like this:

```
void IridiumProcessor::SetNewState(State* pNewState)
{
    if (m_pCurrentState)
    {             
        m_pCurrentState->LeaveState();
        delete m_pCurrentState;
    }    
    m_pCurrentState = pNewState;
    if (m_pCurrentState)
        m_pCurrentState->EnterState();
}
```

On Entering IdleState, I hook up the single shot timer:

```
void IdleState::EnterState()
{
    QTimer::singleShot(1000,this,SLOT(OnTimeout())); 
}
void IdleState::OnTimeout()
{
    qDebug() << "IdleState OnTimeout";
}
```

Same thing happens, when I use a QTimer membervar instead of the static singleShot call.

Comment: While I was trying to reproduce this problem, a question arose: where exactly do you call SetNewState() and doWork()? Is it a single-threaded application? Could it be that you're blocking the event thread with some lengthy operation?

Answer (score 1):

I see only few possible reasons for this to happen, except for really hardcore bugs like memory corruption and such.

It could be that you call your EnterState() method before the timeout expires. The second call cancels the previous one, and it repeats just again and again. In order to debug this, you should add a debugging output to the EnterState() method, preferably with time, to see if it actually happens. If it doesn't, then it means I'm wrong here.

It could also be that you destroy the receiver before the signal is emitted, as chalup suggested.

Another possibility is that you're blocking the event thread with some lengthy operation. The timer won't fire until the control returns to the Qt event loop of the thread where the timer lives. In case of a single-threaded application it is the main event loop.

Comment: Well, my log shows no anomalies - IdleState gets constructed, state is entered, timer fires, IdleState gets destructed, then constructed again, Timer is set again but never fires.

Comment: @zeroc8, and after QTimer is set again, the IdleState::EnterState() is not called any more for the same object? Did you check that? Which version of Qt and on which platform do you use by the way?

Comment: I'm using 4.7.0, 32 Bit on Xubuntu 10.10

Comment: @zeroc8, I don't think the address is the problem here. It's not that Qt remembers and "black-lists" all the addresses of the objects that existed at some time and then were destroyed. I'll look into it further.

Comment: I checked the constructors as well as the memory addresses, everything seems fine here.

Comment: @zeroc8, why did you delete your comment about checking that IdleState::EnterState() isn't called again? That's different from constructors.

Comment: Because the thing with the same memory address was misleading. That wasn't the cause. Sorry bout that.

Comment: @zeroc8, you couldn't possibly get the same address anyway, because you create the new state first and delete the old one later.

Comment: 1)SetState(new IdleState), 2)SetState(CSQState), 3)SetState(IdleState) allocates the same memory address for 3 as it has for 1.  But I forced it to allocate a new address by creating a new temporary IdleState object before the call to SetState(new IdleState) and that didn't change anything.

Comment: @zeroc8, ah, I see, it's because of the intermediate state. Of course it will reuse the same address. Have you tried making a small self-contained separate application that demonstrates this issue? This should at least tell us whether it's a bug in Qt or in your application.

Comment: @zeroc8, I mean, of course, the issue of QTimer not working the second time, not the (non-existent) issue with the addresses.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add logs to IdleState destructors: maybe you destroy them in IridiumProcessor::SetNewState before the QTimer times out?

Also consider using [QStateMachine](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstatemachine.html) instead of writing your own solution.

Comment: Did that already. The object is alive at that point of time. I did consider QStateMachine, but opted for a handwritten statepattern instead.